# Update progressbar while export files

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a project I'm currently working on. It is a C# WinForms project.Basically, the use is supposed to load a file.dat and process that file to export in other format that generate some files. The problem starts when i need to update a progress bar while the export function is running, because the method export is in other class from other assembly, because i separate my project in 3, i have a dll that is a common method to a console app and graphic app so i cant change the method export from the dll, because the console app depends on that implementation.

I have a form that permit open a file and click in export button, when i click on export, create a new form and the progress bar begins to be update while export method works. In the export method, i can't add more parameters because other class depends on the initial implementation.

So i need to know how to update a progress bar while process files in method, each input file generate more than 1 files.

My export function is:

This is in one class from one assembly:

```
     public static void Export(File file, string output, string inputFile,BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        //Other operations
        //......
        // 
        for (int m = 0; m < variable.Count; m++)
        {

            ExportoFile(varibel, output);
            worker.ReportProgress(m + 1);
        }
            worker.CancelAsync();

    }
```

As you see, now i have that and in this way the program works.

And this is another class (Form) from other assembly:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;       
        Exporter.Export(file, output, inputFile, worker);

    }


    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The progress percentage is a property of e

        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressLabel.Text = ((100 * (e.ProgressPercentage))/size ).ToString() +"%";
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == size)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

From my Form I create a backgroundworker, that updates the progress when i export one file. But i need another way to handle that, because my export method is wrong. I don't have to send a worker as parameter, because the original method doesn't have and other class depends on the original implementation.

In conclusion, how can I update a progress bar while export files from other class in other assembly without modify my export method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not send a backgroundworker to your Export method via Parameter. In my opinion you can use a simple event.

You need to extend your Exporter class with one new Event. Because this event is new your dependency shouldn't be a problem.

So your Exporter class look sth. similiar like this:

```
public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Percentage {get;set}
}

public class Exporter
{
     public static event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ReportProgress

     public void Export(File file, string output, string inputFile)
     {
        for (int m = 0; m < variable.Count; m++)
        {      
          ExportoFile(varibel, output);
          ReportProgress(this, new ProgressEventArgs {Percentage = m + 1};
        }        
      }
}
```

Your DoWork will implement this like this:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{  
   Exporter.ReportProgress += reportProgress; //Make sure you call this once      
   Exporter.Export(file, output, inputFile, worker);   
}

private void reportProgress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
   //use e.Percentage
}
```

Further there shouldn't be a problem if you add a new parameter to your method, if you use overloading.  So your approach would still work. But using the event approach is much cleaner.

Comment: But, i can do that without change the method Export to public? The others class call this method statically.

Comment: Your Export Method was public before. In your code it's still public. Static and public has no connection.